# VPN access but can't Remote Desktop after changing subnet

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, subnet

I have VPN access setup through my Meraki MX100 firewall, and can VPN no problem.

Remote Desktop was working perfectly fine on the VPN but a couple of days ago just stopped working.
I get the usual Windows message "Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote conputer"

This happened after I changed our office's subnet.

I've tried turning off the Windows firewall on both machines but that didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: I've similar problem to access HTTP server over LAN after changing the subnet. I can not fixed the actual problem.